# Creating a UDF for MySQL in Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-2007, user-defined-functions

How do I create a UDF for MySQL using Delphi?

Does anyone have any code templates?

I want the code template to be integrated in Delphi versions(2007 and upper), so I need these templates to be usable with and without Unicode support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, Google reveals:

- [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-udf.html)
- [a forum thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?118,57815,57815)
- [an example](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=58)

You need to create a DLL with a few exported functions, as documented.